# Formula for the coefficients in the expansion of $(1+r+r^2+\cdots +r^k)^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Is there a formula for the coefficient of $r^i$ in the expansion of $(1+r+r^2+\cdots +r^k)^n$?  I can get upper bounds on these coefficients by looking at the Taylor series of $(1+r+r^2+\cdots)^n=\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-r)^n}$, but I was curious if an explicit (perhaps relatively clean) formula is known.

Comment: Have you read the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)?

Comment: I had not until I read your comment, but I am on the Wikipedia page now and it seems to be exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1945436/265466, of which this is basically a duplicate. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353249/multinomial-coefficients-definition-in-expansion-of-1xx2-cdotsxln Might also be helpful.

Comment: The multinomial theorem is a good starting point, but you’re going to have to sum over partitions of $i$.