# Looking for Distinct solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=100$ such that at least one of them should be greater than 40

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

For this problem suppose that the $x_i$'s must be non-negative integers, i.e., $x_i∈{0,1,2,⋯}$ for $i=1,2,3$. How many distinct solutions does the following equation have such that at least one of the $x_i$'s is larger than 40?
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=100$$
I tried using different methods but I think I got closest with advanced PIE:
I thought to do it with complement, such that $20\le x_i \le 40$, because if any of them are less 20 one must be greater than 40.
have in the back of your mind that without restrictions there are ${102\choose 2}$ solutions.
firstly i  took those $20$s and gave to all $x_i$s and got $$x_1+x_2+x_3=40$$ such that  $0\le x_i \le20$ and after that did PIE method which gave me $231$ solutions. Lastly, I did what it was asking for $${102\choose 2}-231$$ I think thins answer is too big to be true, so please help me

Comment: The correct answer seems to be [$4920$](https://tio.run/##VY3BDoIwDIbve4oeuwTMUA9e8OKTDBzaBNallASffrKEYOypX/@vbfrom@PlliRnmhKLAmkQZR5nMwhP0PM4hl6J4wy78eAlbpJJQlHR7IjzMiHdrw4GFiCgCKsFU2AtgOirrmqcq33dbQEcVZQtK9Lx/JSEn0uvKD6@AjausZWEFLy2579lGmC/eW/db27N0dicvw)

Comment: Subtract the required $40$ from both sides, then count the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=60$ and multiply by $3$ as for each solution we can add the required $40$ to any of the three variables.

Comment: @K.defaoite You need to subtract $41$, since the condition is that some variable is _strictly_ greater than $40$. Furthermore, your method will double-count solutions where two of the variables are strictly greater than $40$.

Comment: @Mike Earnest Good observation. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem, your method is correct. Here is another method which gives the same answer.

The number of solutions where $x_1\ge 41$ is the same as the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=59$, which is $\binom{61}2$. To account for $x_2$ and $x_3$ as well, you multiply by $3$. However, this double counts the solutions where $x_1\ge 41$ and $x_2\ge 41$. After subtracting these double-counted solutions, the total number is
$$
3\binom{61}2-3\binom{20}{2}
$$
You can verify this gives the same answer as your method.

Comment: thank you for another method, nice to see different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

If we denote $x_1=x,\,x_2=y,\,x_3=100-x-y$ then looking at the inequalities plot we realize that all the values fits except for the shaded region
$$\begin{cases}
x\le 40\\ y\le 40\\ x+y\ge 60
\end{cases}$$
[image]
Which occupies $\frac{21^2+21}{2}=231$ of total $\frac{101^2+101}{2}=5151$ of $(x,y)$ values,
thus the answer is $5151-231=4920$.

Comment: nice visualization of the problem, very useful

Answer (score 2):

By complementary counting and generating functions, this is the number of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $100$ into $3$ parts (there is a formula in the linked article), minus the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the expansion of $$(1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{40})^{3}.$$ See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945436/is-there-a-nice-way-of-expanding-multinomials-of-the-form-1x-cdotsxln?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a general way of computing such a coefficient (the formula in that link can be proven by the principle of inclusion-exclusion). Unfortunately, the overall formula that we get by this method is not closed, and I have not seen a closed form for such a problem anywhere.

Comment: Multinomial expansion to get the $x^{100}$ coefficient,  I assume? Nice work, upvoted.

Comment: @K.defaoite yes, it is a multinomial expansion in a sense, but I prefer to not think of it that way because the multinomial theorem involves more than one variable, whereas the expression whose power is being taken here is just a finite geometric series in one variable. As a result, the multinomial theorem is not directly applicable and the coefficients here are more complicated than the coefficients in the multinomial theorem. And yes, we are seeking the coefficient of $x^{100}.$

Comment: I must admit generating functions are something I know very little about.

Comment: very good usage of generating functions, at the moment i know very little about it but i will learn it with respect.