# When looking for distinct solutions such that xi cannot be larger than a number, how do you find the double counted elements?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, inequality

Based off of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729197/looking-for-distinct-solutions-to-x-1x-2x-3-100-such-that-at-least-one-of-th) question, where we have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 100, \exists x_i > 40$. From here I understand the first part of the calculation, where since $x_i > 40$ the strict inequality yields such that $x_i \geq 41$. If we take this for each $x_i$ we can attain something like $\binom{59+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{61}{2}$ and since this can occur in three ways (one way for each $x_i$) then we get a total of $3\binom{61}{2}$.

However this double counts solutions where two or more of these variables are greater than 40. The consensus on that question was that the end solution was $4920$, any suggestions on how to approach the issue of double counting?

Comment: The double counting is handled by subtracting $3\binom{20}2$ from $3\binom{61}2$ which is number of solutions of $a+b+c=18=100-2*41$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3729284/75923).

Comment: @drhab Thank you! If you made that a formal answer I would definitely mark it, I just didn't know the RHS of $100 - 2 \times 41$.

Comment: You are welcome. I did (and will) not publish as answer because IMV the credit should actually go to the linked answer in my former comment. I only encountered that.