# How can I calculate the coefficient of $ \ x^{21} \ $ in the polynomial $(x^3+\dots+x^{10})^4$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, generating-functions

I tried to develop the expression, use the multinomial theorem or using some combinatorial formula, but I couldn't succeed. Any hint will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A combinatorial problem.  How many ways can you write $21 = n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4$, where all $n_i \in \{3,4,5,6,7\}$ ?

Comment: write your attempts, please. And are you asking coefficient of $x^{21}$

Comment: @LionHeart Yes, I am asking for that. Now I am going to write what I have thought.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the advice. I rewrited $(x^3+\dots+x^7)^4$ as $x^{12}(1+\dots+x^7)^4$. As we are searching for the coefficient of $x^{21}$, it is enough to impose that $x^{n_1}x^{n_2}x^{n_3}x^{n_4}=x^{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4}=x^{21} \Leftrightarrow n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=21$. Since $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_3\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, we are being asked for the $21$-combinations on a set of $4$ elements. I mean, ${4+9-1 \choose 9}=220$. Is it everything correct?

Comment: Using SageMath, I figure out that 204 must be the solution, so I don't really know where is my mistake.

Comment: For this particular case, you could first calculate $(x^3 + \cdots + x^7)^2 = x^6 + 2 x^7 + \cdots + 5 x^{10} + \cdots + x^{14}$; then, find the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in the square of that.

Comment: @chervasss $(x^{3}+\dots+x^7)^4 \neq x^{12}(1+\dots+x^7)^4$ but instead $(x^{3}+\dots+x^7)^4 = x^{12}(1+\ldots+x^4)^4$ so it is the same as writing $9$ as a sum of $4$ elements of $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: @ItsTrex Sorry, I copied it wrong. The sum was supposed to be until $x^{10}$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc How? When I use SageMath, I clearly see 204 is the answer. That answer gives 495 instead.

Comment: Related [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3656079/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1353249/11619).

Comment: Also, please add your thoughts **into the question body**. They are not necessarily seen by the reviewers in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dividing out by $x^{12}$, we equivalently want the coefficient of $x^9$ in $(1 + x + \dots + x^7)^4$. Write this as

$$\begin{align*} \frac{(1 - x^8)^4}{(1 - x)^4} &= \frac{\sum_{i=0}^4 (-1)^i {4 \choose i} x^{8i}}{(1 - x)^4} \\
 &= \left( \sum_{i=0}^4 (-1)^i {4 \choose i} x^{8i} \right) \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {j+3 \choose 3} x^j \right) \\
 \end{align*}$$

which gives that the coefficient of $x^9$ is equal to

$${9+3 \choose 3} - {1+3 \choose 3} {4 \choose 1} = 204$$

which can be checked by direct expansion in WolframAlpha, for example. Your argument in the 4th comment giving ${12 \choose 3} = 220$ overcounts a bit because you have not used the constraint that $n_i \le 7$ and this needs to be accounted for e.g. by inclusion-exclusion. The expansion above is equivalent to some inclusion-exclusion argument and of course generalizes just fine if all the specific exponents here are replaced by arbitrary non-negative integers, as is done in [both](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656079/coefficient-of-xi-in-xx2-xkn?noredirect=1&lq=1) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353249/multinomial-coefficients-definition-in-expansion-of-1xx2-cdotsxln?noredirect=1&lq=1) Jyrki links to in the comments (which I didn't see before writing this, alas).

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful. I think you wrote ${{j+3} \choose 3}$ instead of ${{j+3} \choose j}$.

Comment: Those are the same. I like writing it this way because it's easier to tell that it's a polynomial in $j$ of degree $3$.

Comment: @ QiaochuYuan True! Thanks.