# Extracting coefficients with the power series $(1-x)^{-n}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

Given polynomials of the form $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^k)^n $$ We can calcualte the coefficients by writing it in the form $$(1-x^{k+1})^n \over (1-x)^n$$ and using the power series $(1-x)^{-n}$, as has been explained nicely on SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656079/coefficient-of-xi-in-xx2-xkn?) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533346/how-can-i-calculate-the-coefficient-of-x21-in-the-polynomial-x3-d?)  among other places. Thank you all.
Just curious to know where these methods orignated from. Euler seems unaware of it, instead employing a simple but very cumbersome method [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505425).

Also is there any reason to prefer using $$(1-x^k)^n \over (1-x)^n$$ over using the equivalent $$(x^k-1)^n \over (x-1)^n$$ or is it just a convention of sorts that everyone uses the former?

Thank you.

Comment: My personally preference is to go back and forth between $~\displaystyle (1-x^k)^n \over (1-x)^n ~$ and $~\displaystyle (x^k - 1)^n \over (x - 1)^n~$ depending on whether $~x < 1~$ or not.  I prefer that the denominator, with the $~n~$ exponent ignored, be non-negative.