# Number of permutations in the symmetric group $S_n$ composed of $k$ disjoint $m$-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> Find the total number of permutations in the symmetric group $S_n$ that are composed of $k$ disjoint $m$-cycles, for valid $m$ and k.

I  encountered a simpler version of this question in class for $m=k=2$. They way I solved the $m=k=2$ version is:

First chose $4$ numbers out of $n$, which can be done in $\binom{n}{4}$ ways, now for each of these selections we can make a few of the permutations included in the set, since the permutations we are counting are of the form: $(ab)(cd)$. Now of the four different numbers you can form $\binom{4}{2}$ couples but since disjoint cycles commute in $S_n$ we divide by $2$, which gives the result:
$$\frac{{\binom{n}{4} \cdot \binom{4}{2}}}{2}$$
I had a homework task to create a generalisation of any of the problems we had encountered in class, solve it(by help if necessary) and then present it in class, of which I created this generalization which is the given problem.

I've tried the exact same way for the generalization but there are some things I've used here that aren't valid for the generalization one of which is that $(ij)=(ji)$, and I'm stuck on how to generalize the solution.

Any help is appreciated on how to tackle the generalization or suggest any different routes I could take to generalize it for example removing some restrictions and any suggestion on how to tackle it.

Comment: Your formula, for the $(2,2)$ case is correct, but phrased oddly.  Why not first choose $2$ elements, $\binom n2$ ways to do that, then another $2$ elements, $\binom {n-2}2$ ways to do that, then divide by $2$ to kill the redundancy.  Making the answer $\binom n2\times \binom {n-2}2\times \frac 12$.  Seems simpler and a whole lot easier to generalize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  combinatorial classes  as in  *Analytic Combinatorics*  by
Flajolet and Sedgewick we  have the following class $\mathcal{P}$
of permutations with **exactly** $k$ $m$-cycles

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{P} = \textsc{SET}(
 \textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+\textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots
\\ 
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=m-1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=m+1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots
) \times
\textsc{SET}_{=k}(\textsc{CYC}_{=m}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This gives the EGF

$$G(z) = \exp\left(z
+ \frac{z^2}{2}
+ \cdots
+ \frac{z^{m-1}}{m-1}
+ \frac{z^{m+1}}{m+1}
+ \cdots\right)
\frac{1}{k!} \left[\frac{z^m}{m}\right]^k
\\ = \exp\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{z^m}{m}\right)
\frac{1}{k!} \left[\frac{z^m}{m}\right]^k
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z} 
\exp\left(-\frac{z^m}{m}\right)
\frac{1}{k!} \left[\frac{z^m}{m}\right]^k.$$

Extracting the coefficient on the EGF in $z$ we find

$$n! [z^n] G(z)
= n! [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z}
\exp\left(-\frac{z^m}{m}\right)
\frac{1}{k!} \left[\frac{z^m}{m}\right]^k
\\ = \frac{n!}{m^k k!} [z^{n-mk}] 
\frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left(-\frac{z^m}{m}\right)
\\ = \frac{n!}{m^k k!} 
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor - k} 
[z^{n-mk-qm}] \frac{1}{1-z}
[z^{qm}] \exp\left(-\frac{z^m}{m}\right) 
\\ = \frac{n!}{m^k k!} 
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor - k} 
[z^{qm}] \exp\left(-\frac{z^m}{m}\right)
\\ = \frac{n!}{m^k k!}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor - k} 
[z^{q}] \exp\left(-\frac{z}{m}\right).$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{n!}{m^k k!}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor - k} 
\frac{(-1)^q}{m^q q!}
\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sim}
\frac{n!}{m^k k!} \exp(-1/m).}$$

Observe that when  $n=mk$ so there are no other  cycles this will
produce  $\frac{n!}{m^k  k!}.$ Note  also  that  e.g. it  is  not
possible to have  exactly $n-1$ fixed points in  a permutation of
length $n$  because the last fixed  point is forced to  join. And
indeed setting $m=1$ we get (derangement numbers appear)

$$\frac{n!}{k!} \sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{(-1)^q}{q!}
= \frac{n!}{(n-1)!} \sum_{q=0}^1 \frac{(-1)^q}{q!}
= n \times (1-1) = 0.$$

We  can  verify these  numbers  with  Maple using  the  following
compact code:

```
with(combinat);


pet_disjcyc :=
proc(p)
local dc, pos;

    dc := convert(p, 'disjcyc');

    for pos to nops(p) do
        if p[pos] = pos then
            dc := [op(dc), [pos]];
        fi;
    od;

    dc;
end;

ENUM :=
proc(n, m, k)
option remember;
local perm, res, fact, mat;

    res := 0;
    perm := firstperm(n);

    while type(perm, `list`) do
        fact := map(nops, pet_disjcyc(perm));
        mat := select(len -> len = m, fact);
        if nops(mat) = k then
            res := res+1;
        fi;

        perm := nextperm(perm);
    od;

    res;
end;

X := (n,m,k) ->
n!/m^k/k!*add((-1)^q/m^q/q!, q=0..floor(n/m)-k);

AX := (n,m,k) -> n!/m^k/k!*exp(-1/m);
```

Comment: Indeed in the previous answer given as I checked the answer of kabenyuk I overlooked the fact that if m=1 then for every k other than n the result should be zero, since actually you can’t have exactly k fixed points (other than n) and be part of the set we are counting. For the other values of m it seems to be fine since we are filling with fixed points. This insight was very helpful. I also fail to understand why inclusion-exclusion must be used here (it could of course) since the cycles in the product are disjoint.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Very nice and instructive answer. (+1)

Comment: @123 I have added the PIE argument, see my other answer below.

Answer (score 5):

For arbitrary integers $m>1$ and $k$ and $n\geq mk$ the number of all permutations which are the product of exactly $k$ independent cycles of length $m$ can be computed by the formula
$$
((m-1)!)^k\frac{1}{k!}\binom{n}{m}\binom{n-m}{m}\ldots\binom{n-(k-1)m}{m}=\frac{n!}{m^kk!(n-mk)!}.
$$

If $k=m=2$ we get the OP formula or the same formula given by @lulu in the comment.

PS. By the way, this formula is useful for $m=2$ in one of the proofs that the group $S_n$ at $n\neq6$ has no outer automorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

For PIE  we need to choose  the required poset which  consists of
nodes $Q_S$ where $S$ is a set of disjoint $m$-cycles chosen from
the $m$-cycles that can be formed using the elements of $[n].$ We
build rows for fixed cardinality  of $|S|.$ We consider the poset
spanned by  the nodes on  row $k$ and the  top row, i.e.  the row
where $|S|=\lfloor  n/m\rfloor.$ The weight attached  to the node
$Q_S$ is $(-1)^{|S|-k}  {|S|\choose k}$ and the  poset is ordered
by subset inclusion of $S$. The permutations that are represented
at each node  consist of the $|S|$ cycles of  length $m$ with the
rest  being   arranged  at   liberty.  The  cardinality   of  the
permutations represented at a node  $Q_S$ is thus $(n-m|S|)!.$ We
now  count  the permutations  represented  by  the nodes  of  the
subposet  according to  their weight.  Do this  in two  ways: the
intersection with row $p$ contains

$${n\choose m,m,\ldots,m,n-pm}
\frac{1}{p!} (m-1)!^p
= \frac{n!}{m^p p!}
\frac{1}{(n-pm)!}.$$

nodes. The weight  on these is $(-1)^{p-k} {p\choose  k}$ and the
cardinality  of  the set  of  permutations  being represented  is
$(n-pm)!$ for a total of

$$\sum_{p=k}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor}
(-1)^{p-k} {p\choose k} \frac{n!}{m^p p!}
\\ = n! \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor -k}
(-1)^p {p+k\choose k} \frac{1}{m^{p+k} (p+k)!}
\\ = \frac{n!}{m^k k!} 
\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor -k}
\frac{(-1)^p}{m^p p!}.$$

Good, this is our claim. Now to  count in the second way, what is
the total  weight on a  permutation with  precisely a set  $P$ of
$m$-cycles  where  $k\le  |P|\le  \lfloor  n/m  \rfloor.$  It  is
represented  at all  $Q_S$ where  $S\subseteq P$  and $|S|\ge  k$
giving the sum

$$\sum_{S\subseteq P, |S|\ge k}
(-1)^{|S|-k} {|S|\choose k}
= \sum_{p=k}^{|P|} {|P|\choose p} (-1)^{p-k} {p\choose k}.$$

Now a permutation with $|P|=k$ i.e. exactly $k$ $m$-cycles therefore
contributes with weight one, as desired. For $|P|>k$ we find

$$\sum_{p=k}^{|P|} (-1)^{p-k}
\frac{|P|!}{(|P|-p)! \times k! \times (p-k)!}
\\ = {|P|\choose k} \sum_{p=k}^{|P|} (-1)^{p-k}
{|P|-k\choose p-k}
\\ = {|P|\choose k} \sum_{p=0}^{|P|-k} (-1)^{p}
{|P|-k\choose p} = {|P|\choose k} (1-1)^{|P|-k} = 0.$$

We see that permutations with more than $k$ $m$-cycles contribute
with weight zero, which concludes the PIE argument.

Shown below is  an alternate enumeration routine  to verify these
data  which is  a  bit  more efficient  than  iterating over  all
permutations.  Rather,  we iterate  over  cycle  shapes which  we
obtain from the cycle index of the symmetric group.

```
with(numtheory);
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


ENUM :=
proc(n, m, k)
option remember;
local permtype, res;

    if n=1 then
        return `if`(m=1 and k=1, 1, 0);
    fi;

    
    res := 0;

    for permtype in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        if degree(permtype, a[m]) = k then
            res := res + lcoeff(permtype);
        fi;
    od;

    n!*res;
end;

X := (n,m,k) ->
n!/m^k/k!*add((-1)^q/m^q/q!, q=0..floor(n/m)-k);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we use PIE, the *[principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)*
in order to calculate the number $\color{blue}{A_k}$ of permutations of $S_n$ with **exactly** $k$ $m$-cycles.

We consider $m$-cycles of a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ as *properties* of this permutation. Let $T$ be a set of properties, i.e. a set of $m$-cycles. We denote with
\begin{align*}
N_{\supseteq T}&=\#\{\sigma\in S_n:\sigma\mathrm{\ possesses\ }\bf{at\ least}\mathrm{\ the\ properties\ in}\ \it{T}\}\\
N_{= T}&=\#\{\sigma\in S_n:\sigma\mathrm{\ possesses\ }\bf{exactly}\mathrm{\ the\ properties\ in\ \it{T}}\}\\
\end{align*}

The number of permutations with $k$ (or more) cycles of length $m$ is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{T: |T|=k}N_{\supseteq T}}&=\binom{n}{m}\binom{n-m}{m}\ldots\binom{n-(k-1)m}{m}
\frac{(m-1)!^k}{k!}(n-km)!\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{n!}{m^kk!}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We recall the *generalized inclusion-exclusion* principle. Given
\begin{align*}
N_{\supseteq A}=\sum_{T\supseteq A}N_{=T}\tag{2.1}
\end{align*}
it follows that
\begin{align*}
N_{= A}=\sum_{T\supseteq A}(-1)^{|T|-|A|}N_{\supseteq T}\tag{2.2}
\end{align*}

> We use (2.2) to calculate the number $\color{blue}{A_k}$ of permutations of $S_n$ with **exactly** $k$ $m$-cycles. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A_k}&=\sum_{A:|A|=k}N_{=A}\\
> &=\sum_{A:|A|=k}\sum_{T\supseteq A}(-1)^{|T|-|A|}N_{\supseteq T}\tag{$\to \mathrm{(2.2)}$}\\
> &=\sum_{T:|T|\geq k}(-1)^{|T|-k}\sum_{A:|A|=k, T\supseteq A}N_{\supseteq T}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{q=k}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{q-k}\binom{q}{k}\sum_{T:|T|=q}N_{\supseteq T}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{q=k}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{q-k}\binom{q}{k}\frac{n!}{m^qq!}\tag{$\to \mathrm{(1)}$}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor-k}(-1)^{q}\binom{q+k}{k}\frac{n!}{m^{q+k}(q+k)!}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{n!}{m^kk!}\sum_{q=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor-k}\frac{(-1)^{q}}{m^qq!}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the answers from @MarkoRiedel.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we exchange the sums.
- In (4) we observe that $N_{\supseteq T}$ does only depend on the *number* of $m$-cycles in $T$. We can therefore factor out $\binom{|T|}{|A|}=\binom{q}{k}$.
- In (5) we shift the index to start with $q=0$.
- In (6) we cancel and rearrange a little.

Answer (score 0):

By combinatorial species we have to count ***labelled k-sets of m-cycles***.

The species formula is

$$ Ens_k(Cyc_m(X)) $$

Passing to e.g.f we get

$$ egf(x) = {1 \over k!} ({x^m \over m})^k = { x^{mk}\over k!m^k} $$

Since there are $mk$ labels, we are now interested in the coefficient of $$ { x^{mk}\over (mk)!} $$

which is the well known

$$ (mk)! \over k!m^k $$

Comment: Some people are amazed about the operations with combinatorial species/classes. Where is the rabbit in the hat ? A closer look reveals  that the cycle index operations are cycle-wise. Behind everything in the front end there is in the back end a "gear algebra" passed by mathematicians probably because it looked like a dirty engineering clockwork.

Answer (score 0):

(I feel like someone is missing here)

The legacy solution :

- take the multinomial coefficient $ \binom {mk}{m,m,...m} $
- since order does not matter, divide this coefficient by k!
- then, for each part of size m, define (m-1)! cycles.

$$ \binom {mk}{m,m,...m} {1 \over k!} (m-1)!^k = {(mk)!\over m!^k}{1 \over k!}(m-1)!^k = {(mk)!\over m^k k!} $$